# Makefile Conditionals directives

Tags: linux, makefile

Below is the snippet of Make file:
Makefile1:

```
bar = true
foo = bar
ifdef $(foo)
frobozz = yes
endif
all = ; @echo The value of frobozz is $(frobozz)
```

Makefile2:

```
bar =
foo = $(bar)
ifdef foo
frobozz = yes
else
frobozz = no
endif

all = ; @echo The value of frobozz is $(frobozz)
```

In both the cases the output is the same **"yes"**.

So what I concluded is:

- In the first case the argument for ifdef is $(foo) that ultimately becomes bar means the statement actually looks like **ifdef bar** so the value of bar is cheked.
- In the second case the argument for ifdef is foo directly so value of foo is checked so the statement ifdef checks the value of foo that is $(bar).

First of all I want to know that am I interpreting correctly or I perceived wrong.

If I am getting it correctly then the value of bar in second case is empty so it should give **no** rather than giving **yes**.
Please clarify ... Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Makefile1

First of all, note that according to your assignment, *foo* is set to *bar* not to *true*, but it might be as intended if you wanted to save in *foo* not the value of *bar* but the name of variable *bar* itself.

Then, note that in **ifdef $(foo)** directive actually applies not to the variable *foo* itself, but to variable that will be produced after expansion of *$(foo)*, since syntax for this directive is *ifdef < variable_name >*. In your case *ifdef $(foo)* will be be equivalent to *ifdef bar*.

- Makefile2

**ifdef** does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty, only tests whether a variable has a value. So,

> If I am getting it correctly then the value of bar in second case is
>   empty so it should give no rather than giving yes.

is not correct. The value is empty, but it has a value.

> Consequently, tests using *ifdef* return *true* for all definitions except
>   those like *foo =*. To test for an empty value, use *ifeq ($(foo),)*

from [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html).

So, for **ifdef** there is a difference between *foo* and *bar* which we can see from the following experiment:

```
 bar=
 foo=$(bar)
 $(warning origin=$(origin foo), flavor=$(flavor foo), value="$(value foo)")
 $(warning origin=$(origin bar), flavor=$(flavor bar), value="$(value bar)")

 ifdef foo
 $(warning foo defined)
 else
 $(warning foo is not defined)
 endif

 ifdef $(bar)
 $(warning bar defined)
 else
 $(warning bar is not defined)
 endif
```

Output:

```
 Makefile:3: origin=file, flavor=recursive, value="$(bar)"
 Makefile:4: origin=file, flavor=recursive, value=""
 Makefile:7: foo defined
 Makefile:15: bar is not defined
```

However, you can force expansion with just little change: adding colon when assigning variable foo: **foo:=$(bar)**, and both will be not defined:

```
 Makefile:3: origin=file, flavor=simple, value=""
 Makefile:4: origin=file, flavor=recursive, value=""
 Makefile:9: foo is not defined
 Makefile:15: bar is not defined
```

Comment: It means **ifdef foo** ckecks only that foo has value **$(bar)** it does not expands it further or It expands but does consider empty as a space.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh yes, in other words, it tests that foo is "defined", as operation ifdef suggests. you can use function origin() to test if variable is undefined

Comment: Yes means what it checks that foo has value $(bar) and it does not expand further to check value of bar or it allows empty values to be defined as well like bar = . Please clarify.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh Yes means that it checks that foo has been assigned to some value and doesn't expand further.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh I made some experiments and updated the answer to clearly see what happens. thanks for the question since it provokes restless mind as mine to think about subtle details

Comment: When we write ifdef $(bar) then we are saying expand it as ifdef <space> because before applying ifdef make substitute the variable to a name of some variable then it checkes that is it empty or not. Then what we are achieving by saying ifdef $(bar) because ifdef will first substitute the $(bar) I think ifdef $(foo) will make more sense. Please throw some light on it because I am doing the makefile first time and want to have a good understanding on it because it is required for huge and complex project on supercomputer. Thanks

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh I updated answer, when bar is empty, and we do  ifdef $(bar) then it is very likely happens as you describe. I only didn't get what you mean by "I think ifdef $(foo) will make more sense"

Comment: I thought writing ifdef $(foo) will reduce to a variable name but $(bar) reduce to a value itself . So as per makefile ifdef  statement it is given a variable name to operate .  But I thought by $(bar) we are giving the value that is the only thing nothing much I have to convey may be It does not have a big issue since I read so I have put it .

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh It's all become consistent if we assume that in ifdef $(var), $(var) is expanded before operation, however as I said, this may work differently on ather make (it looks like on make port for Windows, it's not expanded beforehand). So, ifdef $(var) becomes ifdef bar, and ifdef $(bar) becomes just ifdef. This might be strange, but make allows empty ifdef without error and it behaves as "not defined".